# Letting my IDE know about undeclared properties of a class, or declare properties later

Tags: php

This is an example:

```php
class a {  
    private $arr = NULL;

    public function __construct(array $arr) {
        $this->arr = $arr;
    } 
    public function __get($name) {
        return $arr[$name];
    }
}
```

this is a simple example. What i would like to do that
`$class = new a();`    `$class->` and pressing `->` I'm getting the dropdown list of properties he has declared, but I would like to get those throught `__get()` magic methods. Is there any chances to declare properties later IN CODE or something?

Comment: See [phpDoc `@property`](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html). Most decent IDEs recognize them.

Comment: Nice, yes, it's almost what i need, but can i set them dinamicaly ? becouse while i'm setting in the __construct(array $arr) i don't know what the $arr is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to "add" them using annotations in doc comments

```
/**
 * @property int $myProperty
 */
class a {
  // class body here
}
```

Most IDEs should understand it (I only know PhpStorm and Eclipse/PDT).

Comment: almost, but can i set them somehow dinamicaly ?, becouse i don't know what array i can get in the constructor

Comment: No, you can't. How, do you think, an IDE should suggest you with completion for magic properties, if you don't know them yourself? ;)

Comment: i was thinking about defining properties in a constructor, when i know exacty what they will be

Comment: If you know the properties, when you define the constructor, why don't you just implement the properties directly? Beware of too much magic!

Comment: i meant that when i will get the $arr in the constructor, then i will know the properties ^^

Comment: Either _you_ know the properties, than you can define them explictly. Or you _don't_ know them, but the programm do, then the IDE cannot know them either and code completion may contain everything. There is no such thing like "I don't know them, when I write the class, but I know them, when I write the constructor". And again (really): Beware of too much magic. ;)